# excel functions counting production - name strings against list of name strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sounds mysterious but maybe pictures will help:
I have a range of text strings (list of products) - 100 - 500 different names:
[image]

this is a list of products that we need to manufacture. Each one of them has unique name (column A: B.13 B.14 etc) , we need different quantity of each of those (column B) and each one of them has different area (column D) we need a way to track down number of pieces and calculate area of every type manufactured (there might be more than one piece needed)
Then, we are manufacturing few of them every day and we manually write down their names:
[image]

Because it lasts months usually and we need to know exactly how many of which we do have, and how many more are left for manufacturing, and how many have me manufactured in terms of pieces and area.
Currently we use crazy long functions that excel doesn't accept sometimes because formula exceeds 8100 letters:
to get number of pieces manufactured every day we use:
`=COUNTIFS(L7:L49,list!A2:A261)` from manually entered manufactured product references (each column above is different production day
and to get area manufactured we use another function:
`=COUNTIF(L7:L50,"N1.1")*VLOOKUP("N1.1",list!$A$2:$W$300,3,0)`

but they get crazily long if the list form first picture has a lot of unique names/types:
[image]

(this is just a part)

What I would like to achieve is:
check daily manufacturing list AGAINST full list of types and calculate area of daily manufactured products every day.
Anyone that has an idea how to deal with it?

I tried to use an array and `countifs` but couldn't manage to get any result working

Comment: You really need to reduce your samples. Use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to generate usable data tables into your question (Only data to reproduce your issue).
With given sample data, show expected result and explain why.
(also why explain the headers in the text if you can include them in the data table?)